# Переназначение WebViewClient. Как?

Tags: java, android

Назначаю настройки для webViewClient. Но переназначить из другой функции не могу. Тут назначаю и работает и корректно:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        SimpleWebViewClientImpl webViewClient = new SimpleWebViewClientImpl(this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
```

И после определённого события, хочу переназначить этой функцией

```
    public void pereNaznachenie()
    {
        PereNaznachenieClass webViewClient = new PereNaznachenieClass(this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

    }
```

Ошибку выдаёт

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void android.webkit.WebView.setWebViewClient(android.webkit.WebViewClient)' 
on a null object reference
```

Помогите, кто сможет. Спасибо!

Comment: у вас объект `webView` не инициализирован на момент вызова метода `pereNaznachenie()`

Comment: и как мне то сделать? в методе не онкреейт?

Comment: Добавляю webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); .. но тогда опять ошибка

Comment: а в какой момент вы вызываете метод `pereNaznachenie()`?

Comment: public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                        MainActivity mActivity= new MainActivity();
                                        mActivity.pereNaznachenie();

                                        dialog.cancel();

                                    }

Comment: дак у вас не вызывается метод `onCreate` в данном коде, вы просто создаете объект, но не запускаете Activity. А `onCreate` вызывается когда Activity  запускается. Activity же запускается через Intent.

Comment: А как через Intent в данном примере корректнее запустить?

Comment: Мне вообщем то Activity не нужно запускать, оно уже запущено, нужно просто сделать изменения в настройках WebViewClient

Comment: Если обработчик кнопки диалога находится внутри класса активности - то можно вызывать её метод без ссылки или через специальную ссылку `MainActivity.this`. Если он где-то в другом классе или он сам статический, то нужно туда передать ссылку на активность. В общем если не понятно - покажите весь код, с этим связаный.

Comment: Дело в том что суть, мне нужно переназначить shouldOverrideUrlLoading с другими параметрами, для этого я создал копию класса, который отлично запускается и подгружается к WebView из onCreate .. Но из дополнительной функции void не хочет работать

Comment: Я вам комментом выше написал что делать и что делать если вы не поняли что делать;) Или показывайте код, чтобы вам на конкретном примере пояснили, или берите учебник и читайте про внутренние, вложенные и анонимные классы, а также про переменные и область их видимости - здесь вам пол учебника расписывать никто не будет.